# Other way to pass data from block to controller Magento

Tags: magento

I'm pretty new to PHP programming and Magento. I wanna to pass the current ProductId from a form within a custom block to a controller (new action).

Yes I know that one method would be to add an input hidden (with my product id) in the custom block form and then to retrieve the Value through a regular:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost('myvalue'))
```

Is there a better way in Magento to retrieve the value within the controller without having to declare extra secret input fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good for you for wanting to adhere to best practices within Magento! The passing of data to controllers is pretty standard, however. If we look at how the product is added from a product page, we'll actually see the product ID in the form action URL's parameters:

`http://domain.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/uenc_value/product/45573/`

...where `45573` is the product ID. Of course this can also be sent to the controller via a hidden input field, which I use all the time. Note that the above is the same as `http://domain.com/checkout/cart/add/?uenc=uenc_value&product=45573` in Magento.

Another way of storing data for use in controllers for future use is setting data into a session. For posting data to a controller I wouldn't recommend this method but it's something to keep in mind:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$session->setMyValue(true);
```

We can then retrieve the data from `my_value` later just by instantiating the session. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Passing your data could be done in different ways :

1. You could use Magento's [magic setters and getters](http://codemagento.com/2011/02/where-are-my-getters-and-setters/).
   So you would have to do this to set the value :

   ```
   Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSomeVariable($value);
   ```

   and this to retrieve it :

   ```
   Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSomeVariable();
   ```
2. Or you could use the register.

   ```
   Mage::register('key', $value); //to set your data
   Mage::registry('key'); //to get your data
   ```

Comment: Registry is not persistent across execution scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides a way to construct a URL with the necessary values, calculated against the configuration DOM. Blocks (and therefore block templates) can call `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::getUrl()` directly:

```
$this->getUrl('some_handle/foo/test',array('id'=>'some_value'));
// Mage::getUrl() will work as well
```

The above would result in the following URL:

```
http://base_url/frontname/foo/action/id/some_value/
```

...which can be read in the `FooController` `testAction()` as

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('id') // 'some_value'
```